# List of C++ libraries for Graph Theory

Tags: c++, graph-theory, subgraph, isomorphism

I'm going to start a scientific project about automata and graph theory, and I'm searching for a graph library that supports features like:

- directed/undirected graphs
- graph isomorphism test (i.e. is graph g1 isomorphic w.r.t. g2?)
- subgraph isomorphism test (i.e. is a graph g1 isomorphic to a subgraph of g2?)
- graph search, visits and such
- possibly, quite fast since I need to make some serious computations

I know about the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/), but it lacks subgraph testing as far as I understood from its documentation.

So, my question is: which are the best c++ graph libraries, please?
They do not have to provide support for every feature I need, I know it's certainly possible that no existing library fits perfectly my needs.

Comment: What are your need? Specify which features you need. This makes making suggestions easier.

Comment: @RedX: I expanded my needs a little but, but basically the main points were already in my question: subgraph/isomorphism relations tests.

Comment: I almost forget to mention it, but I will make heavy computations... performance is a plus :)

Comment: At whoever downvoted and voted to close as "not constructive": please be constructive yourself, and explain what is wrong in my question in your opinion, as it's not clear at all to me. I required specific features and asked for a list of libraries that satisfy them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use iGraph: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/ which is a C library which should satisfy what you are after.

There is also <s>http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/</s>, there is a related SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751826/which-c-graph-library-should-i-use.

I have not used ubigraph so cannot comment on that, I mainly use networkX and iGraph

**UPDATE**

It seems that ubigraph is dead now so only igraph is maintained currently

Comment: That seems like a good choice indeed, thank you for your suggestion. The only thing that concerns me is the date of the latest release, that goes back to 2010... is it a discontinued project?

Comment: No it is still active, mainly python bugs are being fixed, it also interfaces with R but it is quite popular in open source usage there is a also ubigraph which has c++ bindings http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/

Comment: @EdChum: That link is dead now, it seems...

Comment: @einpoklum thanks for letting me know,will remove it

Answer (score -1):

You may use Cliquer library http://users.tkk.fi/pat/cliquer.html for all calculations related to finding cliques.