# Create a Directed weighted graph

Tags: java, c++

I want to create a directed weighted graph and then run dijkstra algorithm and A* algorithm.
I can use if I want graph libraries, And I can write it with c++ or java.
What is the best way to do it? can you recommend a good graph libary?

Comment: [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) is a good place to start, for C++.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and use libraries. People get PhDs creating them and work in labs and research centres to improve them. It's their job.

Here is the link related to java:
[Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)
Here is c++:
[List of C++ libraries for Graph Theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171331/list-of-c-libraries-for-graph-theory)